# Get the right number og rows in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a large table in a MySQL database.

If I make a search `SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY uid DESC` I get 889285 rows.

If I make another search `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE uid > 0 ORDER BY uid DESC` I get 932156 rows.

Shouldn't the first search give at least the same amount as the second search?

Comment: Yes, of course it should. Seems either your tool fails to fetch all rows or rows have got inserted between running the two queries. What does `select count(*) ...` tell you?

Comment: WHERE uid > 0 - uid can never be null?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Oops... I was inattentive...

Comment: select count(*) gives me 932156